# How to connect "using" keyword with Deconstruct method

Tags: c#, using, idisposable

im wondering if we can join [using statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) and [deconstruct operation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/functional/deconstruct#user-defined-types). To be more visual look at below sample:

```cs
using System;

public class Foo : IDisposable
{
    public IDisposable Bar { get; set; }
    public IDisposable Baz { get; set; }
    public void Deconstruct(out IDisposable bar, out IDisposable baz)
    {
        bar = Bar;
        baz = Baz;
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Bar.Dispose();
        Baz.Dispose();
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        // using var foo = new Foo(); // this is ok 
        // var (bar, baz) = new Foo(); // this is also ok, but i need to dispose each variable
        using var (bar, baz) = new Foo();  // this gives error
    }
}
```

I'm wrongly assuming that statement `using var (bar, baz) = new Foo();` should work? My theory is that both deconstructed variables implements `IDisposable`, even class `Foo` itself implements it, but all im getting is IDE errors.

Do you have any ideas why this is not working?
How can i dispose all deconstructed values in single call?

Comment: The target of `using` has to be a single value that can be converted to `IDisposable`. But why would you want to do this? If `Foo` owns `Bar` and `Baz`, it should be what disposes them (as your code does). `using var foo = new Foo();`.  If `Foo` *does not* own `Bar` or `Baz`, it should not be allowed to dispose them, and the owner shuld do that instead.

Comment: isn't `var (bar, baz)` of type `Tuple` in the end? And `Tuple` doesn't implement `IDisposable`, so...

Comment: @defaultUsernameN: No, it's tuple *notation* but it declares two variables, `bar` and `baz`. `Deconstruct` gets called to assign both of them.

Comment: @madreflection they are not variables, they are _members_ of the tuple type, in this case of `System.ValueTuple<IDisposable,IDisposable>`. We can use them as if they are variables, but they are still fields of a class underneath the syntax. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples

Comment: `using var foo = new Foo();` is *already* disposing `bar` and `baz`. What more do you need? Are you just unhappy that you have to write an extra line to deconstruct it?

Comment: @defaultUsernameN: Jump to the [Use cases of tuples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples#use-cases-of-tuples) section where it says `var (minimum, maximum) = FindMinMax(ys);`... `minimum` and `maximum` are separate variables. The tuple returned from `FindMinMax` is deconstructed. The line following that refers to them individually, not as tuple members.

Comment: @madreflection You're right! My bad =)

Comment: I wonder, actually, if that still might be the reason for it not working. Like, `var (bar, baz) = new Foo()` does assign to variables, but what does it return in relation to the `using` statement? Is it still a tuple at that point?

Comment: @defaultUsernameN: Back to my very first comment: it's not a tuple at that point so it can't be used with `using`, since `using` can only be used on a single value.

Comment: @defaultUsernameN That don't work because `deconstruct` method returns void. and using statement works only with IDisposable. it is more clearly when i write using statement without sugar syntax ```using var ((bar, baz) = new Foo()) { } ``` Maybe it could work if the method `public void Deconstruct(out IDisposable bar, out IDisposable baz)` could return `IDisposable` :)

Comment: @madreflection The warning it gives is CS1674, "(IDisposable bar, IDisposable baz): Type used in a using statement must be implicitly convertible to System.IDisposable". And you can dispose multiple objects of same type with one using statement (`using(Foo foo1 = new Foo(), foo2 = new Foo()`) works fine). Sorry to drag on, but it is actually interesting =)

Comment: It's an *error*, not a warning. It's a misleading error message because it's produced before deconstruction is applied. As for `foo1` and `foo2`, those are separate targets, each of which is a *single value* convertible to `IDisposable` so that's a specious argument.

Comment: How would we know the error is "produced before deconstruction is applied"? It does know the types of resulting variables at compile-time, why would it wait to deconstruct? That would be  strange - to produce errors before the code is actually checked

Comment: We know because without the `using`, it deconstructs the value and no tuple is used at all.  See [this](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgZgpghgLgrgJwgZwLTIgWwJaqnGAe1QAcFCTkAaGEbAGyoBMQBqAHwAEAmARgFgAUEM4BmAAQ9JvAOxCA3kPHLJ3bkpWLBKneIBuUBOIAUwQ1XFmAXgEpxAXnEA7CAHdxAMUKFjNgNziAPSB4jAAFtjI4pHiUPTIhOKEANYWwATRzhAQTKGJTJEkhBji0ADGYfqG2FDA9BAaygC+Qi3CgmKqnt7iIOIAkgAihcW19QqNkhJDI8hjEOIAQobi8uIA5hAwARjb4m06nTPIRXN1C8tWqxtbO7f7k52cACzigxBlhE7IMAhwZTBjIQMsdTvNLOYkiDhidRucIbZJlpdCozEZHMsEH5JjprA4llArNjtCoDionq8YacIL4kTiVJiAHRU4o0/z05SXZmzNnEnRtNpAA).

Comment: `ValueTuple` doesn't appear anywhere in the resulting IL. The compiler goes through many levels of translation. The mention of `ValueTuple` in the error message means that it hasn't translated the assignment to a deconstruction yet when it checks for convertibility to `IDisposable`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guess i was overthinking too much. The @Sweeper got me on the right track. **I cannot do everything in single line**. I can still use `using` statement and shortly after do `deconstruct` and it still look nice and tidy.

```cs
using var foo = new Foo();
var (bar, baz) = foo;
```

Thank you for your comments :)

Comment: @DStanley Usings without braces use the containing block, ie dispose at the end of current method/if body/ etc.